# Downloading pdf file using Python

Tags: python, pdf, httprequest, httpresponse, urllib

I am working on an API which returns me a document ID and then I can use that document ID to get the PDF. For example `document_id = 'fanlfe48ry4ihkefewfl934'`. Now I concatenate this id like the following

```
document_id = 'fanlfe48ry4ihkefewfl934'
full_url = url + document_id

from urllib.request import urlopen

response = urlopen(full_url)
file = open("document.pdf", 'w')
file.write(response.read())
file.close()
```

But it is getting just an html response. The reason is that the url is not a file with .pdf extension but it is a url which when clicked, pops up the window for save location and then it saves the file as pdf. 
I don't understand how to handle this situation

Comment: How does your url look like ?

Comment: Does the website work with javascript disabled? Python doesn't run javascript for you.

Comment: See [**`urlparse.urljoin`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin)

Comment: Currently I am using an API to get the data. So currently its like `http://localhost:5000/download?document_id=fanlfe48ry4ihkefewfl934`

Comment: maybe you should first scrape out the second url.

Comment: better show real url so we could test it.

Comment: BTW: what do you get in this HTML when you try to download ? maybe there is some useful information.